# How to restart state before git stash save --keep-index?

Tags: git

I'm doing

```
cd $(mktemp -d)
git init .
echo a > a
git add a
git commit -m "Initial commit"
echo b > b
git add b
echo c > b
git stash save --keep-index
```

Now, if I do

```
git stash apply --index
```

or

```
git stash pop --index
```

I'm getting a merge conflict for `b`. Using `git stash push --keep-index` doesn't change the result.

I'd like to get to the state before `git stash save` which is having `b` with content `b` staged and `b` with content `c` as unstaged change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it's generally best to pop stashes when the worktree is clean.  This is especially true if using `pop --index` because with this option you can't resolve conflicts.

If you had created the stash without the `--keep-index` option, then it would've reset your state to the previous commit, and a subsequent `git stash pop --index` would work fine.

If your test is deliberately simulating a case where for some reason you want to keep the index state modified even though you are stashing it, but then want to reapply the stash to get back to where you started, you'd have to first return the index and worktree to the state of the previous commit (run `git status` to see what needs done), and then you will be able to pop the stash cleanly.

Comment: This is the right answer; to ensure clean-ness, you need a `git reset --hard` or equivalent. Using `git reset --hard` is correct and safe *if* you did a normal, full stash; if you did one with pathspecs it's trickier.